# AngularJS Dependency Injection Fails in module

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection, typescript

i have a problem regarding the angular dependency injection mechanism.
I have written a directive in a standalone module, that does some neat things on a datatable. I'm using TypeScript and my directive looks as follows:

```
export class MdListControls implements angular.IDirective {
  public templateUrl = "/app/templates/mdListControls.html";
  public static instance(): any {
    return new MdListControls();
  };

  public restrict = 'E';
  public transclude = true;
  public replace = true;
  public scope = {
    grid: '=',
  };
  public controller = "mdListControlsController"
  public controllerAs = "vm";

  public link = function (scope: angular.IScope, element: angular.IAugmentedJQuery, attrs: angular.IAttributes) {

  };
}
```

My Controller looks something like this:

```
export class MdListControlsController { 
  static $inject = ['scope']
  constructor($scope: angular.IScope){
    //Setup the constructor
  }
  //Here goes the controller Logic
}
```

I'm registering the directive and the controller at a new module as follows:

```
angular.module("base.directives.mdListControls", [])
  .controller("mdListControlsController", MdListControlsController)
  .directive("mdListControls", function () { return MdListControls.instance() });
```

However, once I run the app, I get the following error once the directive shall be loaded:

```
Argument 'mdListControlsController;' is not a function, got undefined
```

This doesn't quite look like a problem with dependency injection at first. But when I register the controller on the application itself (which gets injected the "base.directives.mdListControls" Module) like so

```
app.controller("mdListControlsController", MdListControlsController);
```

everything works fine and the controller gets injected properly into the directive.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here?
Thanks for your help!

Comment: I don't know TypeScript but the problem is order of JS execution. MdListControlsController is not available when your controller is being registered as angular.module("base.directives.mdListControls", [])
  .controller("mdListControlsController", MdListControlsController)

Comment: I don't know TypeScript either. What happens if in your controller declaration you do .controller("mdListControlsController", function () { return MdListControlsController }) ?

Comment: Maybe a stupid question. But you seem to export MdListControlsController. Do you also import it at the top of your directive module file?

Comment: @DaanvanHulst: Both the MdListControls and the MdListControlsController classes lie wihtin the same typescript namespace, thus I don't need to import it.

Answer (score 0):

In Your MdListControls class try to provide controller class, not controller name.

```
...    
public scope = {
    grid: '=',
  };
public controller = MdListControlsController
public controllerAs = "vm";
...
```

Comment: Thanks for your hint. That obviously works, because the "injection" know happens on TypeScript level. But now angular does no dependency injection here at all. However, I guess I'll have to go with that solution.